# Conteúdo assíncrono para mobile

Tags: ajax, media-queries, layout-responsivo

Estou trabalhando em um novo projeto de site, onde algumas áreas necessitarão de um tratamento especial do html para apresentação. Por exemplo: para o desktop, temos um carrossel de imagens 1920x800, enquanto que no mobile, desejo trabalhar com um carrossel 768x1024.

São imagens diferentes e para não sobrecarregar o carregamento, gostaria de entregar a versão correta para cada dispositivo de acesso [mobile, desktop]

Minha ideia foi utilizar o carregamento assíncrono via javascript, onde eu detecto o window.width e verifico se a tela é maior ou menor que 1024px.
A partir deste resultado, eu busco via ajax o conteúdo html adequado.

Gostaria de saber se vocês conhecem/sabem de outros meios para chegar a este resultado. Obrigado!

Comment: Utilize bootstrap mas o nome do que você quer em específico se chama 'css media query'

Comment: Vc deveria ver era a largura do dispositivo (768px) e não a altura. Ou seja, ver se é menor ou igual a 768px.